# Install packer in Jenkins slave using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. I created a Dockerfile and install packer in it. Then I created a image using that Dockerfile. After that I create a slave in my Jenkins configuration. And created a new item in jenkins and try to build it. But it does not work.

```
FROM jenkinsci/jnlp-slave
USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unzip 
RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/1.3.2/packer_1.3.2_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip packer_1.3.2_linux_amd64.zip -d packer
RUN mv packer /usr/local/
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/packer/

ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-slave"]
```

This is my Dockerfile. I created this Dockerfile by reading the Docker documentation. And I build this Dockerfile by running the following command.

> docker build -t pack .

And I successfully built the image. And I tried to run my image using powershell and I got successful result.

And I created a Jenkins slave using this image.[image]

After that I tried to execute the following item in Jenkins.

```
node('packer'){
  sh 'packer --version'
}
```

Then it not build. I go to the console output and found that following command only shown in the console output in Jenkins.

> Still waiting to schedule task ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘packer’

I searched through the stackoverflow and do not find this problem in all resulted problems.

Comment: The image states that the entrypoint must accept Jenkins slave parameters. As you have not overridden the entrypoint in your example, I suspect it is running the entrypoint with `packer` attached and failing. Maybe try with the base image and work from there

Comment: Thank you I change the entrypoint to jenkins-slave. but still getting the same problem

Comment: did you remove the `CMD` entry? as the `sh 'packer --version'` will run in the job, well after the slave is connected

Comment: yes I removed it and add ENTRYPOINT there

Comment: maybe do a `docker ps -a` on the box to see if its trying to start a container. Then hopefully do a `docker logs` on an exited container to check its problem

Comment: I checked it but it doesnot start the container I erase all the cache now it work.